# Encrypting Kubernetes cluster's admin.conf ($KUBECONFIG) at rest

Tags: kubernetes, security, encryption

I have been concerned about leaving `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` (i.e. `$KUBECONFIG`) unencrypted on disk, for it essentially contains a Kubernetes cluster's root credentials, and an intruder could obviously do a lot of harm with those.

So far, I have kept `admin.conf` encrypted with [`encfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS) and have for the most part resorted to unencrypting it (manually) only in cases of emergency (when I could no longer log into the Kubernetes cluster with an administrator OIDC token). This has served well for several years. But the simple encryption layer has its downsides: in particular, it makes cluster upgrades with `kubeadm upgrade plan` somewhat brittle. I just ran into an error "failed to renew certificate [...] unable to sign certificate admin.conf", which could be related. My current hunch is that I better decommission the `encfs`-based mechanism and investigate more suitable alternatives.

Hence I am wondering: can Kubernetes [Key Management Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kms-provider/) (KMS) and its providers (e.g. [Thales](https://cpl.thalesgroup.com/resources/encryption/kubernetes-secrets-encryption-integration-guide) KSM Plugin) also manage `admin.conf` encrypted at rest, or do those only have secrets (inside etcd) in their scopes? I suspect the second is the case, but want to be sure, for I am facing an important (re)design decision.

P.S. I also noticed that various security controls (e.g. "[C-0104](https://hub.armosec.io/docs/c-0104) - Ensure that the admin.conf file permissions are set to 600") make lighter recommendations. So perhaps the "correct" line of thinking is: `admin.conf` encrypted at rest is too late a line of defense: the focus must be on always keeping intruders off cluster nodes. Or perhaps KSM could not even "bootstrap" with `admin.conf` being encrypted by itself.